# Hide border in HTML Form or Input

Tags: html, forms, input

anybody knows how to hide border in HTML using Form or Input tag?

My Code as below:

```
<form name="timerform">
    Your session will expired in
    <input type="text" name="clock" size="7" value="5:00">
</form>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also use

```
input[type="text"] { border: none }
```

This is usefull when you have other input types, i.e. `type="submit"`, but IE < 8 doesn't support type.

Check [**this with type**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRTPu/) and [**this without type**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRTPu/1/).

**Update:** Also you can use as follows

```
<input style="border:none" type="text" name="clock" size="7" value="5:00">
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRTPu/5/).

Comment: can you teach me how to set that css? it's like this `<style type="text/css">` `input { border: none; }` `</style>`

Comment: `<div align="center" class="input">
    <font size="-2" face="verdana" color="#264F8A">
 <form name="timerform">
 Your session will expired in
 <input type="text" name="clock" size="7" value="5:00">
 </form>
 </font>
 </span>
 </div>`

Comment: yes that work for me, thanks so much but do you know how to make that box invisible because I've grey background page, the current box is white color.

Comment: this one, `<input type="text" name="clock" size="7" value="5:00">` the  original box are white in colour, so how to make the box transparent because my background page is grey in colour.

Comment: Remove the `outline:none` if you want a border when focused.

Comment: hey dude, I got the answer myself, `<input style="border:none; outline:none; background-image:url(images/wall.png)" type="text" name="clock" size="7" value="5:00">`, this that I mean, anyway thanks so much for your guidance and help.
`

Comment: You are welcome but you can `background:transparent` too as I mentioned but anyway, glad to know that you got it. leaving.. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Set the style in CSS. CSS can be applied inline in the HEAD section of the web page...

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
      input { border: none }
      /* other style definitions go here */

    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- your HTML code below... -->
```

or in your case might be easiest just:

```
<form name="timerform">
    Your session will expired in
    <input type="text" name="clock" size="7" value="5:00" style="border:none" />
</form>
```

depending how much you want to do with this page. Further reading: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp